# Pravega Tier2 Storage on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I'd like to configure Pravega Tier2 storage to use AWS S3. My understanding from the [long term storage docs](https://github.com/pravega/pravega-operator/blob/master/doc/longtermstorage.md#use-dell-emc-ecs-as-longtermstorage) is that any S3 compatible backend is supported. However, I can't seem to get this working in my Kubernetes cluster.

I'm using the following manifests secret:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: aws-credentials
type: Opaque
stringData:
  ACCESS_KEY_ID: [AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID]
  SECRET_KEY: [AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY]
```

And the relevant Pravega cluster configuration:

```yaml
storage:
  longtermStorage:
    type: ecs
    ecs:
      configUri: https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
      bucket: "my-aws-s3-bucket"
      prefix: "my-prefix"
      credentials: aws-credentials
```

Using the toy NFS example I can write to and read from a stream. However, with the above configuration the deployment of Pravega fails. Has anyone had any success with AWS S3 as a Tier2 storage?

Comment: If someone with enough reputation is able to create a `pravega` tag that would be super helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for your question. Let me answer:

> My understanding from the long term storage docs is that any S3 compatible backend is supported.

The Long-Term Storage implementation up to Pravega 0.8 supports [NFS](https://github.com/pravega/pravega/blob/ef48f28678ae3bfcb9ecf37dc45abc6d320236c7/bindings/src/main/java/io/pravega/storage/filesystem/FileSystemStorage.java), [HDFS](https://github.com/pravega/pravega/blob/ef48f28678ae3bfcb9ecf37dc45abc6d320236c7/bindings/src/main/java/io/pravega/storage/hdfs/HDFSStorage.java), and [Extended S3](https://github.com/pravega/pravega/blob/ef48f28678ae3bfcb9ecf37dc45abc6d320236c7/bindings/src/main/java/io/pravega/storage/extendeds3/ExtendedS3Storage.java). As you can see in the documentation of the [DellEMC Extended S3 API](http://emcecs.github.io/ecs-object-client-java/latest/javadoc/com/emc/object/s3/S3Client.html), it implements some functionality that is not available in the plain S3 API and Pravega actually requires it. So, unfortunately, this means that up to this version Pravega does not support plain S3 API.

> Using the toy NFS example I can write to and read from a stream.

It is great that you have already tried to [deploy Pravega with Kubernetes on AWS](https://blog.pravega.io/2020/06/20/deploying-pravega-in-kubernetes/). If you want, you can use AWS EFS instead of S3 to deploy a real long-term storage backend.

> Has anyone had any success with AWS S3 as a Tier2 storage?

The good news come with [Pravega 0.9](https://github.com/pravega/pravega/releases/tag/v0.9.0), which was recently released. One of the main novelties of this release is a new feature called [Simplified Long-Term Storage](https://github.com/pravega/pravega/wiki/PDP-34:-Simplified-Tier-2). This feature basically replaces the existing implementation of Long-Term Storage and allows Pravega to work with simpler APIs, like S3 or Google Cloud. This precisely addresses the problem you have experienced. While we still need to create the bindings, I expect that in a relatively short period of time will be able to use Pravega with plain S3.

If you are interested on this topic, you are welcome to join the Pravega Slack: https://pravega-io.slack.com/

Thanks.

Comment: And get a Slack invite here: http://pravega-slack-invite.herokuapp.com/